In a recursive Python function, why does it matter what parameters are returned?
I thought I understood recursive functions but realised I don't actually understand what is happening under the bonnet
Running this Python code to generate a triangular series gives the expected values
def fib(k):
    result = 0
    if(k > 0):
        result = k + fib(k - 1)
        print(f'after call k is {k} and result is {result}')
    else:
        print()
    return result
    #return k

print("Recursion Example Results")
fib(6)

And this is what it returns:
Recursion Example Results

after call k is 1 and result is 1
after call k is 2 and result is 3
after call k is 3 and result is 6
after call k is 4 and result is 10
after call k is 5 and result is 15
after call k is 6 and result is 21

So this is printing intermediate values, but I don't understand why that depends on what is finally returned
So if I change the code to return k:
def fib(k):
    result = 0
    if(k > 0):
        result = k + fib(k - 1)
        print(f'after call k is {k} and result is {result}')
    else:
        print()
    #return result
    return k

print("Recursion Example Results")
fib(6)

I get this:
Recursion Example Results

after call k is 1 and result is 1
after call k is 2 and result is 3
after call k is 3 and result is 5 
after call k is 4 and result is 7 
after call k is 5 and result is 9 
after call k is 6 and result is 11 

Why the difference and how is it calculating this? Why is it not returning k = 1,2,3,4,5,6?

This question is similar to: How do I get ("return") a result (output) from a function? How can I use the result later?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Neither of these are the Fibonacci sequence.

"Why is it not returning k = 1,2,3,4,5,6?" But it is returning k=1,2,3,4,5,6. At any rate you are USING the return of the fib() function as part of your calculation k-fib(k-1), so you will get different values when you return result vs k.

You're not printing the return values, you're printing the intermediate calculations.  If you change your logic to print what you're actually returning, I think you'll see what you expect.

The Fibonacci sequence is F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2).

When you are returning k then result becomes result = k + k - 1 and when you are returning result it performs Additition of all the number in decreasing order, like for 6 it will be 6+5+4+3+2+1

It returns the kth triangular number

In fib(k + 1), the return value of fib(k) is used.
Therefore it matters whether fib(k) returns k or result.
